# Calling a web service to Upload an Excel File using J query with or without Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Am using HTML, Jquery and Ajax. I want to upload an excel file by calling a Webservice in jquery. Please help on this. I don't want any PHP Examples.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use and jquery extension like [this one](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to uploads files.